# Modify search socialengine to search in posts body

Tags: socialengine

I have installed Socialengine on my server and noticed that the search function doesn't search in posts body (activity feeds)
Is there any suggestion to fix that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default socialengine search use the engine4_core_search table. You need to add the activity feed data in that table so activity feed will also be searchable.

Comment: I will try it .. i'm not familiar with zend framework .. what if i did it by sql triggers ? to insert to search table after insert into activity table

Comment: Please check Module->Core->APi->Search.php . Where check getPagination function and add join with activity field table. Hopefully it will work for you.